# Set color for app name text in notification flutter_local_notifications

Tags: flutter, localnotification

I'm using flutter_local_notifications and I am trying to set color for app name text that appears on top of notification. How to change the color to red.

[image: I'm using flutter_local_notifications and I am trying to set color for app name text that appears on top of notification. How to change the color to red.]